# Restrict Special Characters

Tags: jquery

How to Restrict Special Characters using Jquery?

Comment: You have to be more specific if you don't want this posting to be closed.

Comment: First, you define "special characters"

Comment: "special characters"  like superman?? or wonder woman??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah! be more specific.. you might be thinking of [this plugin](http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/).

Comment: This was also my 1st thought. I've used it in quite a few cases, works nicely.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out my mistakes

Comment: yeah... they were just so harsh to close it... I voted to reopen, but still needs 4, I guess... just be clear and specific next time... cheers...

Comment: Thanks Reigel .. sure i will take care of it in future.